# How to Minify PHP Conditional Usages?

Tags: php, class, conditional-statements

I was wondering If I could simplify my PHP condition.

From:

```
/* Do nothing if there are no taxonomies. */
if(!property_exists(__CLASS__, 'taxonomies') || !$this->taxonomies || empty($this->taxonomies) || is_null($this->taxonomies)){
    return;
}
```

To:

```
/* Do nothing if there are no taxonomies. */
if(!property_exists(__CLASS__, 'taxonomies') || !$this->taxonomies){
    return;
}
```

Does `!$this->taxonomies` accomplish `!is_null($this->taxonomies)` and `!empty($this->taxonomies)` as well?

- There must be a class property existent.
- Data must NOT be NULL.
- Data definitely can't be empty.
- Data must never have a false value.

Comment: look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, `!$this->taxonomies` checks if `$this->taxonomies` does NOT contain a value that evaluates to bool false, which includes `empty string`, `NULL`, `FALSE`, `ZERO int`, `empty array` and maybe others.
2. In general, `!property_exists(__CLASS__, 'taxonomies')` seems like a bad design (it depends what you are doing), but in general you should know what instance you are working with and what corresponding interface it should have. So `taxonomies` should be defined and there should maybe even be a getter for it (eg getTaxonomies()) which encapsulates it. Then simple check `if (!empty($obj->taxonomies))` or simply (whatever you like more) `if(!$obj->taxonomies)` should be sufficient.